# Reloading UICollectionView with custom layout throws error

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I am trying to implement apple watch animation on my UICollectionView using this [tutorial](https://www.invasivecode.com/weblog/apple-watch-home-screen-ui-animation/).
It has a separate class of UICollectionViewLayout for desired layout.

I put my elements in the array and when I have to update the collectionview with new values I used to call

```
self.collectionView.reloadData()
```

But it was throwing me following error

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionViewData validateLayoutInRect:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit/UIKit-3600.8.1/UICollectionViewData.m:433

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UICollectionView received layout attributes for a cell with an index path that does not exist: <NSIndexPath: 0x170222520> {length = 2, path = 0 - 1}'
```

Then I used

```
self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
```

to invalidate the layout before reloading. But my code is still throwing the previous error. So I tried reloading sections instead:

```
let indexSet = IndexSet(integer: 0)
self.collectionView.reloadSections(indexSet)
```

This time sometimes the layout is not appearing correctly. It has a distorted UI and sometimes its throwing the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error on the following line of code:

```
 self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout // error comes on this line
```

Any solution for this? Please look at the tutorial mentioned above to understand my code. I referred to many answers but I was not able to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because you're returning **UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes** even when the data is **nil**, thus the error :

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UICollectionView received layout attributes for a cell with an index path that does not exist: <NSIndexPath: 0x170222520> {length = 2, path = 0 - 1}'
```

In the [tutorial](https://www.invasivecode.com/weblog/apple-watch-home-screen-ui-animation/?doing_wp_cron=1496216974.1351740360260009765625), the method `layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath` ,which returns the attributes, is being called from `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect` where the `cellCount` is `cellCount = ROWS * COLS`

Assuming you might have changed `numberOfItemsInSection` to reflect your data, you must change the condition of `cellCount` too.

Comment: The cell count may or may not change, as the data inside the array gets updated.

Comment: @Sabah What I meant was, the `cellCount` is not getting updated here (unless you're doing it)

    for i in 0 ..< cellCount { 
        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: i, inSection: 0) 
        attributes.append(self.layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)) 
    } 

or am I missing something?

Comment: Abdul The condition for cell count has been changed accordingly, `layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath` is returning layout for the cell. Atfter this line `return attributes` executes in `layoutAttributesForElements` , the error comes later

Comment: Umm my bad. Maybe you could try subclassing your `UICollectionView` and invaliding layout using `invalidateLayout` right in `viewWillLayoutSubviews`

Comment: Abdul The issue does seem to be with cellCount, but a little different than what you expected. Thanks for your help. It lead to right direction

Comment: No problem :) Let me know if I can be of any further help.